# Objective-C target not access in Swift target in local package (SwiftPM)

Tags: swift, objective-c, module, target, swiftpm

I have two target in Swift package manager, one is Objective-C target and another one is Swift target. I have few Custom components in Objective-C target and need to access those components in Swift target. I have added Objective-C target as dependency to Swift target in package.swift. Still i am getting error on swift ViewController class showing "Cannot find type 'CustomTextView' in Scope".

I need to access Objective-C custom components from Objective-C target to Swift target in local package.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/72729163/13087977. You need to structure your files that the headers are in the include folder